# Change input value using geb

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, geb

I am using geb and PhantomJS to change an input but after entering the value and sending enter keys, the value does not change (checked by retrieving the attribute). I want to change the value from 0.0 to another number.

Here is the cell that I am trying to fill

```
<input type="text" class="entry" name="fFndNewPct0" size="6" value="0.0" onfocus="westfieldcompnotification(0);" onchange="javascript: return validValue('0');">
```

Comment: How do you verify that the value hasn't changed? Do you take a screenshot or do you just check the value attribute of the element?

Comment: Thank you !!. I took a snapshot and found that the input values were indeed being set correctly and there was another error with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be checking whether the input value changed by checking the `value` attribute on the element. Elements have both attributes and properties. The attribute is the one that you see in the markup and usually it won't change. The property is the one that is changing because of user interaction or JavaScript. When you take a screenshot/snapshot, you will see that the value actually changed as a result of your interaction.